# Using builtin __import__() in normal cases

Tags: python, python-import

Here is where I checked the performance of `__import__()`

```
In [9]: %%timeit
   ...: math = __import__('math')
   ...: sqrt = math.sqrt
   ...: sqrt(7894561230)
   ...: 
The slowest run took 11.16 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 534 ns per loop

In [10]: %%timeit
    ...: from math import sqrt
    ...: sqrt(7894561230)
    ...: 
    ...: 
The slowest run took 10.23 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached.
1000000 loops, best of 3: 979 ns per loop
```

Builtin `__import__` module seems faster than traditional way to import,

So can it be used in code as i have used it, or is there any major harm in doing this, `__import__` doc doesn't state any harm in doing this.

But it states

> Direct use of `__import__()` is rare, except in cases where you want to
>   import a module whose name is only known at runtime.

So my question is can it be used in normal cases too. Or is there any disadvantage of it ?

Comment: After the first `import` it will just look up the module in `sys.modules` and not really *load* the package again. So from your timings you can't be certain which one loads it faster, just which statement is faster in looking it up in `sys.modules`. Was that the intention?

Comment: i checked this on two different terminal, in first i used `__import__` and in second i used traditional way, even then I got the former fast.

Comment: Yeah, but timeit repeats the statement, so actually the first invocation is the one that loads the module. Every other of the 1000000 loops doesn't actually "load" the module.

Comment: @MSeifert Ok got it, but then to isn't `__import__()` doing it faster, or m i missing something.

Comment: Depends on your use-case. If you want to just look it up in `sys.modules` you could just do that without `import` or `__import__`. But if you want to time which one can load a not-cached module faster then you need to do a different kind of timing.

Comment: @MSeifert also there isnt much disadvantage or wrong in using `__import__()` right.

Comment: Follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46175875/7051394

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a small "benchmark". Let's define two functions:

```
def f1():
    import sys

def f2():
    sys = __import__('sys')
```

Bytecode comparison:

```
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  5           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              2 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              4 IMPORT_NAME              0 (sys)
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (sys)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE

>>> dis.dis(f2)
  8           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (__import__)
              2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('sys')
              4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (sys)
              8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             10 RETURN_VALUE
```

The generated bytecodes have the same number of instructions, but they are different.
So what about the timing?

```
>>> timeit.timeit(f1)
0.4096750088112782

>>> timeit.timeit(f2)
0.474958091968411
```

It turns out that the `__import__` way is slower.
In addition, it is far less readable than the classical `import` statement.

Conclusion: stick with `import`.

---

Now for a bit of interpretation...

I suppose that calling `__import__` is slower than executing an `import` statement, because the bytecode generated by the latter is optimised.

Take a look at the instructions: the bytecode for `__import__` just look like any other function call, with a `CALL_FUNCTION` instruction.
On the other hand, the `import` statement results in a `IMPORT_NAME` instruction, which definetely looks like something dedicated to imports, and is probably executed in an optimised way by the interpreter.

As a matter of fact, the third instruction is the only true difference between the two bytecodes.
So the difference between the two functions lies in the difference between `IMPORT_NAME` and `CALL_FUNCTION`.

Comment: Got it !, but what was causing the delay while i was doing `%%timeit`?

Comment: and i did what you demonstrated, but i used `math` module,  `func1` with traditional way gave `0.6304051876068115` and `func2` with `__import__()` gave `0.4561610221862793`. Also i tried with `numpy`, `__import__()` took less time.

Comment: But i surely agree with your last statement of the answer.